# How can i open a dialog after clicking a listview item that are generated by AsyncTask?

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  ListView list;
    LinearLayout ll;
    Button loadBtn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    loadBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    loadBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           LoadContacts lc=new LoadContacts();
           if(lc.execute()!=null)
           {
            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
           }

        }
    });

}

    class LoadContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>>
    {

        ProgressDialog pd;
        @Override
         protected void onPreExecute() {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             super.onPreExecute();

             pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Loading Contacts",
                     "Please Wait");
         }
         protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             ArrayList<String> contacts = new ArrayList<String>();

             Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
                     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                     null, null, null);
             while (c.moveToNext()) {

                 String contactName = c
                         .getString(c
                                 .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                 String phNumber = c
                         .getString(c
                                 .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                 contacts.add(contactName + ":" + phNumber);

             }
             c.close();

             return contacts;
         }
         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> contacts) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             super.onPostExecute(contacts);

             pd.cancel();

             ll.removeView(loadBtn);

             ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                     getApplicationContext(), R.layout.text, contacts);

             list.setAdapter(adapter);

             list.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    adb.setTitle("call & message");
                    adb.setPositiveButton("call", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            //write here call coding

                        }
                    });

                    adb.setNegativeButton("message", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            //write here message coding
                        }
                    });     
                    }               

            });               
 }
}
}
```

This is my `MainActivity.java` file.  When I remove the dialog code its working fine and loading the contacts but with dialog code its not working please anyone help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Just use setOnItemClickListener instead of onClickListener :

```
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                adb.setTitle("call & message");
                adb.setPositiveButton("call", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        //write here call coding

                    }
                });

                adb.setNegativeButton("message", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        //write here message coding
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

call your webservice after

```
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

and  write listview clicklistener after calling webservice in onCreate().

Therefore step will be,

- list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1)
- new LoadContacts().execute()
- list.setOnItemClickListener()

Comment: The AsyncTask is asynchronous, so you can set the item click listener before the execute

Comment: Yes, Thats right. As  AsyncTask is asynchronous, you can call it before also.

Comment: still it's not working if i set the item click listener before the AsyncTask so how it load the contacts from my phone because AsyncTask loading the contacts in ListView..Don't know how it works

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `list.setOnItemClickListener` to click on specific items in the list.

`list.setOnClickListener` will allow you to click on the listview, yes, but it treats the entire list as one giant button.

And you can move that entire block of set Listener code out of the AsyncTask and into onCreate because the AsyncTask only needs to get the list of Contacts and update the listview adapter, nothing more.

Comment: if(lc.execute()!=null)   { list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {AlertDialog.Builder adb=newAlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);adb.setTitle("Select");adb.setPositiveButton("call", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { }});
adb.setNegativeButton("message", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {   
}});} });       this is my code for dialog in onCreate method and its not giving me dialog